# Двойной запрос Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Есть в одной БД 2 таблицы sirovyna (c полями id,naim,kol,data) и zayavki (с полями id,kol,data) . Подскажите пожалуйста каким запросом можно вывести  к таблице zayavki  поле naim с таблицы sirovyna где sirovyna.id=zayavki.id.

Comment: Почитайте про JOIN. А еще советую не называть так столбцы

Answer (score 1):

Вообще, запрос будет выглядеть так:

```
SELECT z.id, z.kol, z.data, s.naim 
FROM zayavki z JOIN sirovyna s ON s.id=z.id
```

Псевдонимы для таблиц я использовал для краткости.
Если нужно, чтобы в ответе БД не было видно, какой столбец к какой таблице относится, то можно использовать псевдонимы для столбцов:

```
SELECT z.id id, z.kol kol, z.data data, s.naim naim 
FROM zayavki z JOIN sirovyna s ON s.id=z.id
```

Кстати, архитектура Вашей БД выглядит подозрительно. Связь двух таблиц по id - это такая штука, которая крайне редко бывает полезной.